# Ionic function works for the first few times and stops working from later shows it is not a function even when nothing is changed

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and trying out simple switching between pages using button

I placed the below code in home.html

```
<button ion-button (click)="callnew()">Click me</button>
```

I place the following code in home.ts

```
callnew() {
    this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);
}
```

In home.ts I have placed the import above

```
import { Page2Page } from'../page2/page2';
```

I have included necessary lines in app.module.ts :

```
import { Page2Page } from '../pages/page2/page2';
@NgModule({declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    Page2Page
],
entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    Page2Page 
],
```

The function works for some 4-5 times then stops later even when nothing is changed. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: so you are not "popping" it off the pages stack just keep pushing the same page in or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine from the code sample you provided, if you're using live reload then it might be the problem as it has a weird behavior that some newer changes are not detected.
if you're using live reload, just go to the home.ts and save it again without editing anything just to force the live reload to be updated and detect the current code used inside this file, if the problem still occurs try to stop the live reload and run again.